# Порядок сложения строки и числа в JavaScript

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Почему может быть такая разница? В IE10 работает одинаково быстро.

```
d = new Date(), s;

for(var i =0; i< 100000;i++)
{
      s = {};

      s["asd" + i] = 123;
}

console.log(new Date() -d); 
d = new Date(), s;
for(var i =0; i< 100000;i++)
{
     s = {};
     s[i+"asd"] = 123;
}
console.log(new Date() -d);
```

Вывод

> 14602 
> 160

Comment: Не знаю что вы тут тестируете, но Chrome не может быть медленней IE — http://jsperf.com/bredo-test

Comment: Запустите этот код в консоле браузера и убедитесь

Comment: Честно горя я в замешательстве, на jsperf всё отлично, но если выполнить отдельно, то и в правду дикий ступор, поспрашиваю у коллег.

Comment: Это какая-то странность Chrome, зачем вы создаете переменную **s** в цикле, в этом нет никакого смысла, посмотрите вот этот пример: http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/26a66888730bc8ea65097b422c34.png

Answer (score 8):

Наблюдаемые эффекты не имеют отношения к скорости сложения числа со строкой. Тут все дело в эвристике, которая решает представлять объект словарем или в структуро-подобном виде.

Все дело в том, что результат `"abc" + i` выглядит как "нормальное" имя свойства и как следствие V8 создает новый *скрытый класс* для каждого присваивания.

Результат `i + "abc"` как имя свойства не выглядит (начинается с цифры!) и как следствие V8 превращает объект в словарь и не создает новых классов.

Если в случае `"abc" + i` не создавать новый пустой объект на каждой итерации, то он достаточно быстро превратится в словарь от переполнения количества быстрых свойств.

Comment: Вячеслав, но почему это происходит только если переменную инитить в цикле + если итераций < 1e5, результаты одинаковые.

Comment: @RubaXa почему не происходит если объект не пересоздавать написано выше: объект быстренько переполняется свойствами и превращается в словарь.

Про 1e5 я воспроизвести не могу, у меня разница видна даже при 1000 итераций. Покажите код, на котором разница не видна, я гляну :-)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Egorov, http://jsfiddle.net/ShQUB/ — просто я выполнил больше чем один раз, а так да, разница всегда присутствует.

Comment: @RubaXa если выполнить второй (третий, N-ный) раз в удачный момент, то скрытые классы для каждой проперти "abcNNN" все еще присутствуют в куче (полный GC не пришел и не собрал их) и их не надо пересоздавать, как следствие будет быстрое исполнение. Если полный GC случился и собрал классы, их надо пересоздавать --- результат медленное исполнение.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Egorov, это понятно, спасибо большое.